# Run a complex linux command in a docker Ansible container

Tags: r, ansible, docker-container

After a long search I did not find the answer

There is a playbook Ansible.

```
- name: myscript
  hosts: myhost
  tasks:
    - name: myscript
      docker_container:
        name: myscript
        image: myimage
        detach: false
        working_dir: "/opt/R/project"
        command: Rscript $(find ./*_Modules -iname *_Script.R)
```

This command works: `Rscript ./01_Modules/02_Script.R`

This command NOT works: `Rscript $(find ./*_Modules -iname *_Script.R)` - Treats `$(find` not as a command, but as a path.

At the same time, in linux, this line is successfully run and finds the script.

How do I pass full-fledged linux commands with `&&` and similar features to command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your problem

```
  - name: Create a test container
    docker_container:
      name: test
      image: busybox
      command: ls |grep var && echo 'it doesn\'t work!'
```

Output :

```
ls: |grep: No such file or directory
ls: &&: No such file or directory
ls: echo: No such file or directory
ls: it fails: No such file or directory
var:
spool
www
```

If I wrap it in quote and use
`/bin/sh -c`

```
  - name: Create a test container
    docker_container:
      name: test
      image: busybox
      command: /bin/sh -c "ls |grep var && echo 'it works!'"
```

Output :

```
var
it works!
```